# How to add link to flash banner

Tags: flash

I am primarily a developer and dont know to use Adobe Flash CS4. Is there a simple way to add link to flash banner. I have .flv file with some items in Library and two layers.
Please, give me step by step instructions.

Edit: I find simple solution, by steps:

1. Go to **File -> Publish settings** and set **ActionScript version** to **ActionScript 2.0**
2. Insert new layer
3. Create a square with **Rectangle tool**, that is larger than banner
4. Right click on square and chose **Convert to symbol...** In popup windows chose **Type: Button**
5. Double click on new button from Library panel and move select from Up to **Hit** and than go back to main scene
6. Right click on new blue square and chose **Actions** and paste this code in soruce editor:

   ```
   on (release) {
       getURL("http://www.example.com/", "_blank");
   }
   ```
7. Close source editor and **export** file as movie (**File->Export->Export Movie**).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a flash FLA file that shows the FLV movie you can add a button inside the FLA file. This button can be given an action to load the URL.

```
on (release) {
  getURL("http://someurl/");
}
```

To make the button transparent you can place a square inside it that is moved to the  hit-area frame of the button.

I think it would go too far to explain into depth with pictures how to go about in stackoverflow.

Comment: I get the error when go to test: 1087: Syntax error: extra characters found after end of program. on (release) {... But I dont see that characters in editor...

Comment: If you go to File > Publish settings... under Flash set your movie to Actionscript 2.0. It should probably work?

Comment: Yes, it helps me to find solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

@Michiel is correct to create a button but the code for ActionScript 3 it is a little different - where movieClipName is the name of your 'button'.

```
movieClipName.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, callLink);
function callLink:void {
  var url:String = "http://site";
  var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
  try {
    navigateToURL(request, '_blank');
  } catch (e:Error) {
    trace("Error occurred!");
  }
}
```

source: http://scriptplayground.com/tutorials/as/getURL-in-Actionscript-3/

Comment: Adobe Flash CS4 is the authoring environment, this doesn't mean you have to code in Actionscript 2.0/3.0 SWF files. Setting publish settings in CS4 to create Actionscript 1.0 SWF files would also be valid.

Comment: @Michiel - yes you are perfectly right - i was just giving the as3 version.

Comment: It pains me to say this, but AS2 is better for banners. For some reason the new VM is under a different popup-blocking scheme in browsers. A trivial getURL() in AS2 works great crossbrowser, but the corresponding AS3 code gets blocked in IE and requires some javascript trickery to work. So stick to AS2 if possible.