# flash banner link not working - AS 2.0

Tags: actionscript-2, flash-cs4

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024454/how-to-add-link-to-flash-banner) had some easy to follow instructions to make a flash banner clickable, but it's not quite working for me.
http://www.austintreeexperts.com/maps/oakwilt.cfm is where my flash banner is.  Under the google earth thing is a small flash ad.  When I mouse over, the cursor turns to pointer like it knows it's a link, but clicking does nothing.  I've been fooling with this for hours and I'm about to go crazy.  My actionscript is this:
on(press){getURL("http://realgreenlawn.com","_blank");}

Answer (score 0):

First thing to consider:

Are you using a button symbol?  If so you will get a hand cursor whether or not the **onPress()** code is correct.  You should use a **movieclip** symbol instead, with your over, up, and down states as frame label names **"_up", "_over" and "_down"**.  Those frame names will make a movieclip act like a button instance as long as you have an **onRelease()** or **onPress()** method assigned to it as outlined below.  Also, to get a hand cursor you will need to set **useHandCursor** to **true**.

Second thing to consider:

Your **onPress()** code looks like its the kind of code placed right on a movieclip.  If so, **do not do that!**  Give it an instance name, like **myButton** and use the code below on the same frame the button resides:

```
myButton.useHandCursor = true;
myButton.onRelease = function()
{
    getURL("http://realgreenlawn.com","_blank");
}
```

or alternatively and **not best practice**, but easier if your aren't that skilled with as2 is to put the above code on the first frame inside your button movieclip, but if you do that change it to:

```
this.useHandCursor = true;
this.onRelease = function()
{
    getURL("http://realgreenlawn.com","_blank");
}
```